# Can a mage wear clothing or robes that gives a bonus to AC?(Dungeons and dragons imaginative game)

Tags: wizard, armor, wizards-of-the-coast

I am ready the build my character, still reading the basic rules. Afterwards I want to create a mage, in my starter set rulebook I read the mage may not wear any type of armor. Looking at a prebuild character sheet which was also included the example is wearing normal clothes. Can I wear robes that give a bonus to AC, magic resistance or spell/ability bonuses, normally I like to consider them as clothing but am I allowed according to the rules of AD&D

Comment: Welcome to the site (and, I presume, the hobby)! Take the [tour]. I assure you the site can totally answer this question, but the site needs to know what edition of *Dungeons and Dragons* your using exactly. You should add that edition as a tag using the `edit` button at the bottom of the question or mention it in one a comment or the question and someone will add the tag for you. Thank you for participating and have fun.

Comment: Are you asking about wearing magical items such as "robe of protection" in this question?  (Also, please specify which edition of D&D you are asking about.  )

Comment: What edition are you playing?

Comment: (Just a note for anyone noticing "AD&D" in the post and wondering why that doesn't settle the edition issue: there's no such thing as AD&D + starter set + WotC.)